# Mark clicked menu item as active

Tags: php, html, css

So I was wondering how to make the menu item that has been clicked, shown as 'active'/'highligted', so the user can see which page they are on?

I've made this menu bar.

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav_menu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav_menu a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav_menu a:hover,
.engine_dropdown:hover .engine_dropbtn {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav_menu">
  <!-- # will be removed for enable redirect -->
  <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
  <a href="#index">Test Runs</a>
  <a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a>
  <a href="#dbOperations">TRT Tools</a>
</div>
```

After the item has been clicked it should appear highlighted.

**EDIT**

So I created a solution, but is that the best way?

Comment: Not really, I want my anchor tag to highlight if I'm on that specific page. So let's say I click on, `profile`, then I would get redirected to that page and it would be highlighted in the menu.

Comment: You're using **anchors** `href="#someAnchor"` - what you mean by *"it gets redirected"*? Anchors do not redirect anything.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes right now it's `#` so yeah `onclick` won't change anything. I just inserted the `#` because I for some reason thought you guys would get redirected away from this page if you clicked it for some reason. so don't mind the `#`. this will mean that if the user clicks on `href="profile"` they will go to that specific page, and that page tab should now be highlighted in the menu bar. Check my awnser.

Answer (score 0):

Created this function to check which page in on, and then if im on that page, I would set the class to `active`

```php
function active($currect_page){
    $url = basename(getcwd())."/".str_replace(".php", "", basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); // If filename is just "name" or "name.php"
    // Also checks which directory the file is in, to avoid highlighting multiple menu items with same name
    // $currect_page == $url :: parentFolder/fileName == parentFolder/fileName (without .php here)
    if($currect_page == $url || $currect_page == basename(getcwd())."/".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){
        echo 'active'; // class name in css
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav_menu">
    <a href="profile" class="<?php active('Test/profile'); ?>"><div id="imgDiv"></div></a>
    <a href="index" class="<?php active('Test/index'); ?>">Test Runs</a>
    <a href="dashboard" class="<?php active('Test/dashboard'); ?>">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="dbOperations" class="<?php active('Test/dbOperations'); ?>">TRT Tools</a>
</div>
```

`active` class would look like this

```css
/* Active menu item */

.topnav_menu a.active,
.topnav_menu a:focus {
    /* When a-tags inside this class has been clicked */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: ...but OP uses Anchors not paths...

Comment: This code is with `<a> = anchors` the only thing this code does is check which page the user is on, and set the class `active` for that specific `anchor`, so the background changes for that specific one. It works well. @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score -2):

Based on how you have written the HTML, bellow js will solve the problem.

```
//JS
let a = document.querySelectorAll('a')

for(let i =0; i< a.length; i++){
    a[i].onclick = function(){
        a.forEach(function(item){
          item.classList.remove("active");
      });
        this.classList.add("active");
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this only work if you didn't get redirected to the `href` page?

Comment: `addEventListener()` should be used instead of `onclick`, also NodeList has the `forEach()` Method, so, no need to `for` loop. PS for the reader: this does not preloads an "active" class on page load - only on click.